# Can't update spriteNode location in spritekit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Basically when the user taps the screen they can add a sprite to the screen, which is contained within a wrapper class called Planet that contains a couple more variables. I stored all the planets in an NSMutableArray, so when the screen is tapped a new planet is created and I add that planet's spriteNode to the view as a child. I want to be able to update values such as the sprite's size and position, but the issue is that I can't seem to be able to do that by accessing the sprite from the planet class in the planets NSMutableArray

basically when the screen is tapped, a planet is added, and until the tap ends, the "update mass" method is called, increasing the size of the sprite a little bit.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
/* Called when a touch begins */
mass = 10;

massTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.2 target:self selector:@selector(increaseMass) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    Planet *planet = [[Planet alloc] init];
    [planet planetWithImage:@"Earth"];

    planet.mass = mass;
    planet.spriteNode.xScale = planet.spriteNode.yScale = planet.mass * .004;

    planet.spriteNode.position = location;



    SKAction *action = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI_2 duration:5];

    [planet.spriteNode runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:action]];

    [self addChild:planet.spriteNode];

    [planets addObject:planet];

    touchBeginX = location.x;
    touchBeginY = location.y;

    break; //only get one :p
}
}
-(void)increaseMass {

NSLog(@"increase mass");
((Planet *) [planets objectAtIndex:([planets count] - 1)]).mass++;
((Planet *) [planets objectAtIndex:([planets count] - 1)]).spriteNode.xScale = ((Planet *) [planets objectAtIndex:([planets count] - 1)]).spriteNode.yScale = .002 * ((Planet *) [planets objectAtIndex:([planets count] - 1)]).mass;
}
```

The planet with image class just create a new planet class with a couple variables and a spriteNode object within it that uses the image called, in this case, @"Planet".

Comment: This might sound silly, but I cant see it in your code,  is planets allocated?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this differently. Have you considered saving the currentPlanet in an instance variable, running an action on that, and cancelling that action in `touchesEnded:withEvent:`?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    mass = 10;
    // grab only the first touch
    self.currentTouch = touches.firstObject;
    CGPoint location = [self.currentTouch locationInNode:self];

    self.currentPlanet = [[Planet alloc] init];
    [self.currentPlanet planetWithImage:@"Earth"];

    self.currentPlanet.mass = mass;
    self.currentPlanet.spriteNode.xScale = self.currentPlanet.spriteNode.yScale = self.currentPlanet.mass * .004;
    self.currentPlanet.spriteNode.position = location;

    SKAction *spinAction = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI_2 duration:5];
    [self.currentPlanet.spriteNode runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:spinAction]];
    SKAction *growAction = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:0.2], [SKAction performSelector:@selector(grow) onTarget:self.currentPlanet]];
    [self.currentPlanet.spriteNode runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:growAction] withKey:@"growAction"];

    [self addChild:self.currentPlanet.spriteNode];
    [planets addObject:self.currentPlanet];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([touches containsObject:self.currentTouch]) {
        [self.currentPlanet removeActionForKey:@"growAction"];
    }
}
```

Then in your `Planet` class:

```
@implementation Planet () 
- (void)grow
{
    self.mass++;
    self.spriteNode.xScale = self.spriteNode.yScale = 0.002 * self.mass;
}
@end
```

This way you are accessing the sprite you care about directly, rather than trying to find it in the array of planets. If this is your only use for that planets array, you could get rid of it if you do it this way.

Comment: ideally I'd like to be able to modify the sprites after they've been created too though

Comment: Then keep the array for use afterwards